# npm ERR! missing script: start react project

Tags: npm, npm-start

I am not able to run my react project. The version of npm and node are as follows:
node -v
v10.12.0
npm -v
6.5.0

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are u running it?

Comment: >>> npm run start

Comment: Try adding sudo if on linux. Also use `npm start` instead of `npm run start`

Comment: tried using sudo still not working. and I am using mac. Is it the problem with the version of npm or node?

Comment: I found the solution. It was related to the webpack. The following commands helped me.
   npm uninstall webpack
   npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
   npm install webpack@4.19.1
   npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.9
   npm audit fix
   npm install